# Rails_admin show image icon in list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I want to show in objects list the icon 'active.ico' if created_at<1.day.ago else
show 'passive.ico'.How would I do that?

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model Player do
    list do
      field :created_at do # (1)
        //if created_at<1.day show 'active.ico'
        //else show 'passive.ico'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pretty_value`:

```
list do
  field :created_at do
    pretty_value do
      # result from here will be passed to a view
      if created_at = bindings[:object].try(:created_at)
        if created_at < 1.day
          image_tag("active.ico")  # <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/active.ico" />
        else
          image_tag("passive.ico") # <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/passive.ico" />
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Then you need to adjust that code sample to your needs. For example, replace it by `image_tag`.